# Django Model/SQL Relationship Error

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm working on a simple forum using Python & Django but i'm running into a small issue when creating database entries for Post:

```
(python manage.py shell):
     >>> from forums.models import User,Category,Post

     >>> nu = User(username="daniel", password="test")
     >>> nu.user_ip = "127.0.0.1"
     >>> nu.save()
     >>> User.objects.all()
         [<User: daniel>]

     >>> c = Category(category_name="Default")
     >>> c.save()
     >>> Category.objects.all()
         [<Category: Default>]

     >>> p = Post(post_name="Test", post_content="Hello, world", category=Category.objects.get(pk=1), poster=User.objects.get(pk=1))
     >>> p.save()
```

> "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py",
>   line 344, in execute
>               return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
>           DatabaseError: table forums_post has no column named category_id

This is my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date

class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    creation_date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    user_ip = models.IPAddressField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.category_name

class Post(models.Model):
    post_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    post_content = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    poster = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.post_name
```

Why is it trying to find the column "category_id"? All help appreciated.

Comment: what is your id column in your database called is it named category_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you specify a `db_column` when you define your foreign keys, Django will append `_id` to the attribute name you give when it tries to query the DB.

I'm guessing in your DB your column is called `category`.

You can either change the column name to `category_id` or define your category foreign key like this:

```
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, db_column='category')
```

Comment: Works.>>> from forums.models import User,Category,Post
>>> user = User(username="daniel", password="test",user_ip="127.0.0.1")
>>> user.save()
>>> cat = Category(category_name="Default")
>>> cat.save()
>>> post = Post(post_name="Test", post_content="Hello, world!", category=cat, poster=user)
>>> post.save()
>>> Post.objects.all()
[<Post: Test>]